# Camera not following my player

Tags: java, libgdx

I have seen many questions exactly like these with the same answer but it never works for me. I have a player who has a position vector that is constantly updating. I need my camera to constantly follow my players position. This is the player class

```
    public void update(){


    //velocity.y += MainScreen.GRAVITY.y;
    velocity.x += MainScreen.GRAVITY.x;


    oldPosition = getGridPosition();

    position.x += velocity.x;
    position.y += velocity.y;


    if(oldPosition.x == getGridPosition().x){
        hasMoved = false;
        System.out.println("Hasn't moved");
        System.out.println("normX- " + position.x);
        System.out.println("oldX- " + oldPosition.x);
    }
    else{
        hasMoved = true;
        System.out.println("Has moved");
    }

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)){
        velocity.x -= 10 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }
    else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)){
        velocity.x += 10 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }else
        velocity.x = 0;


}
```

And I have tried to set the camera position to my players position but it just does NOT for me. Here is my main render loop.

```
    public void render () {
    player.update();
    camera.position.set(player.getPosition(), 0);
    camera.update();
    mapGrid.update();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    mapGrid.render(tmpRend);
    player.render(tmpRend);
}
```

I am at such a loss I don't know what I am doing wrong, here is how I initialize my camera in my create method

```
   player = new Player();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.setToOrtho(false);
    //camera.position.set(MapGrid.MAP_WIDTH / 2, MapGrid.MAP_HEIGHT, 0);
    camera.position.set(player.getPosition(), 0);
    camera.zoom = 2f;
    camera.update();

    tmpRend = new ShapeRenderer();

    tmpRend.setAutoShapeType(true);
    tmpRend.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    input = new InputListener(camera);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(input);
```

Please I have seen many other questions just like this and I am doing what they say but mine just doesn't work. Here is an image to show what happens.[image: Reference to game]

I just don't know why it won't work when I have followed everything I have been told. Any help you can give me would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Make sure you set your `spritebatch`s `projectionMatrix` to `camera.combined`. This makes your `batch` render the things form the cameras viewpoint.

Comment: I did I just didn't show it look at new edit @Springrbua

Comment: You seem to set in in the `create` or somewhere similar, as you also asign the `player` there. Set it in the render loop,  right after the `camera.update()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you already update wrong camera - you've created an instance of it but where it is connected with other part of program?

Use **Scene2d** to manage your actors, viewports and cameras. You can read more about it here:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d

You are creating new stage, add player (which should inherit from **Actor** class) to it and then just instead of creating new **Camera** just get your current stage camera just like

```
    stage.getCamera()
```

all you should do in **render** is

```
    ...

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    this.viewport.update(this.screenWidth, this.screenHeight);
    this.stage.act();
    this.stage.draw();
```

Comment: it is connected to the player I am trying to get the camera to follow the player by setting what the camera position is to the players position, what you are doing is setting the camera to the width and height of the screen. I did this as my viewport but I want the camera to translate with the player. For example, if I move left the camera should be centered on the player. I have moved my character right 5000 and the camera didn't even move an inch

Comment: what I mean is - where exactly you are using your **camera**? Are you sure you are really using **this** camera? 

You've just created some and you are updating it (by the wat update just calculates everything - no action is taken here). When using spriteBatch you have a function like 

    **spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);**

but I don't know what you are using - I encourage you to use Scene2d then

Comment: My camera is being used to project the screen at a given width and height but as you see in my update method I am using camera.position.set(player.getPosition(), 0);
this is how I am using my camera, it is supposed to be following my character. What do you mean "use" my camera, I am setting the width and height of the screen to it in the setToOrtho method and trying to manipulate its position. @m.antkowicz I am using nothing, it is just a shape renderer and I am using renderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined); but that is irrelevant because the position is what is being effected.

Comment: ok and is position updated **before** renderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined); ?

Comment: Yes look at render method

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot see any **renderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);** in your render method

Comment: Completey my fault! No worries!! @ m.antkowicz.